# Custom Styles for Bootstrap NavBar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change bootstrap navbar with completely different styles.

This is how I need to change its default styles -

[image]

At the moment I have completed more than 80% of this work and only thing I can not accomplish is its action of `hover` and `active`.

This is my CSS so far -

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #999999;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
    color: #444444;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #333333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #000000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
    border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 12px 24px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
    background: #53001e;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

So, Can I get any help from professionals here to get this work out without using any image?

[This is the way I have tried it.](http://jsbin.com/podecuju/1/edit)

Any idea would be highly appreciating. 
Thank You.

Comment: What do you want to happen on hover and active?

Comment: @Dan  I need to display a gradient under menu item. (On black background). You can see it on my image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`shadow`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)** property on `:hover` ([browsers that support it](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow)):

I made few changes in your **[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nexenica/1/edit)**:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 18px 17px 0px rgba(152, 46, 255, 0.59);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 18px 17px 0px rgba(152, 46, 255, 0.59);
    box-shadow:         0px 18px 17px 0px rgba(152, 46, 255, 0.59);
}
```

So you can play around with this property if you're OK with IE>=9.0

Comment: Nicolai, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it. Just I found its closing white color bottom border of list items. Any Idea?

Comment: @TNK, this is not possible (at least I don't know how) because you apply `border` to whole menu and it lies under menu item. So could try to apply border to `li` or `a` elements than the border will be shown. [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/nexenica/9/edit)